# Finding the time needed for a pixel to change its color

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have made a tkinter script that changes the colors of all shapes on the canvas and what I want to do Is check how much time does it take for a pixel occupying the tkinter window to change color ,how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do that will give you an accurate answer. Are you changing one pixel at a time and want to measure that? Or, are you changing a large object and want to check the time for one pixel inside that object?

Comment: You title asks about finding the color of a pixel, but the body of your question is asking about how to compute the time it takes to change one pixel. You should make the title and the body be a bit more consistent with each other.

Comment: I am changing the "fill" of a the whole shape but i would like to measure just  the time it would take for a pixel in the shape to change color because otherwise the program would become too slow .

Comment: I suspect the time to fill one pixel is not going to be much different than the time to change hundreds of pixels. There's also the question of exactly what you're measuring -- the time to compute the color of the pixel? The time for tkinter to set the color in the widget? The time it takes for the hardware to render it?

Comment: The time it takes for the hardware to render it

Comment: You cannot get that information from tkinter.

Comment: What would be a good way to measure time it takes for the machine to rander an image , (I am talkin about CentOS X11 remote desktop ) i have tried using libriaries such as PIL but OS seems to not be able to open images using PIL due to the lack of a proper image viewer

Comment: start a timer. Cause the image to be rendered. Stop the timer.